# Can I avoid using migration in EF Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, .net-core, orm

I am creating a ASP.NET web API project and it gets the data from the MSSQL database. After using Scaffold command I have all the models and proper db context, and using fluentApi I have defined some relationships between tables(Key set up, One-to-many relationship). There were no such thing in the SQL server, and I do not want to affect the database. Is it okay not to use migration? (Or in this case we cannot use EF Core for database first approach?)

Comment: As long as you don't execute schema migrations, EF won't touch your database schema. I *guess* that CRUD statements with EF will still work but you can potentially get into inconsistencies when not defining foreign keys on the db.

Comment: I'm also not sure about that, may be it wont be problem. App is only reading the data btw, not Create, Update or Delete

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use migrations with database first approach.
In that case you will have to update your models manually and probably your DbContext every time the database is changed(new table to read from, a new column... ) .
As for the relationships and key sets i would suggest creating Dto classes that have the extra information, if possible you can use inheritance if the properties are the same.
I have used this approach and i would recommend it only if the database contains a lot of tables which have a lot of columns. The reverse of this situation, i created a web api for inserting and updating data with ef core with database first approach without any migrations. While there was a second app that reads the same database by using stored procedures. There can sometimes be concurrency issues with writes, updates and deletes with this approach , like when you are running a query manually in Mssql and are trying to write to the same table through the api, but you probably won't have this problem for only reads.

Comment: I've created some relationships using fluentApi, is there any way that I can test them to see if they are okay? Except migration @terodaktil

Comment: I didn't use FluentApi then, i had the relationships in the database. But as long as the relationships are defined in the DbContext they should still apply. You will probably be able to test them just by using the application. Just force the system into a situation where a certain contraint needs to throw an exception, that's how i tested the constraints from the database. The best way to test if any of them are applied is to add a unique constrain and try to insert a duplicate.